# How do I use XSD as ReportViewer data source in MVC4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, reportviewer

I have a report (rdlc) in my MVC4 project.  I was able to add to display it, but the following error keep appearing:

```
A data source instance has not been supplied for the data source
```

How do I use the XSD I have created to use as the rdlc's data source?  The XSD pull up multiple stored procedures.

Comment: By XSD do you mean a XML schema document?  Or something else?

Comment: Yes.  You are correct.  XML Schema.